# How to limit thread pool size in MongoDB async driver

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive-streams

According to [JAVA-2561](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2561), it is possible to limit the number of threads created by the MongoDB async driver since release 3.6.

However, I couldn’t find any documentation about how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After inspecting the commit linked by D. SM, I could find out that you need to specify an `AsynchronousChannelGroup` when creating the `AsynchronousSocketChannelStreamFactoryFactory`, which in turn you provide to the client settings:

```java
var channelGroup = AsynchronousChannelGroup.withFixedThreadPool (10, Thread::new);
return MongoClients.create (MongoClientSettings.builder ()
    .streamFactoryFactory (AsynchronousSocketChannelStreamFactoryFactory.builder ()
        .group (channelGroup)
        .build ())
    .build ());
```

`AsynchronousChannelGroup` has several static factory methods, use the one that best match your needs.

With the 4.0.4 MongoDB driver (at least), in case no group is specified, the JVM system-wide default group is used, which is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

The work appears to have been done in [this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/commit/19336af05937e8a986cc583af6f86688bedf32a6). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it helped! Inspecting that commit led me to a solution, see my own answer.